# How to create custom cocoa touch framework with storyboard

Tags: ios

I'm following [this tutorial](http://insert.io/frameworkios8xcode6/) to create a custom framework. I have tried the source code as in that tutorial, excepts that when building the framework, I just select "Build Only Device>Generic iOS Device" and press Command+B, instead of using the build scripts introduced in that tutorial. It works fine for me with the source code copied from that tutorial.

After that, I tried to build my own framework with storyboard and build it like above, then try using it in a simple test app. The framework built successful but when I include it in the test app, it doesn't work. The error message is:

[image]

I am using the latest version of xcode and mac osx. My entire source code for both test application and simple framework is in [this link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ht9ldw7gb9st215/SourceCode.zip). Please take a look and help me find what is going wrong. Thanks so much!

---

#### Solved

I just find out why. It seems like that is because I have opened both Test Application and the framework project in two workspaces. Closing the framework project before import it to the Test Application solve the problem.

Comment: Looks like your framework is not build for the simulator.

Comment: select target of project - >build settings - > search paths ->always search path YES and check framework sarch path and library search path

Comment: @vaibby I have tried but it doesn't works too...

Comment: @dasdom I don't think so. As I described, I have tried this build method and it works fine on simulator, I still don't test it with real device.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check target membership at right pane for this class? 
Check all boxes if it is empty.

Comment: I don't understand what you means. But I think I have configured public headers, included resources and compile resources right. You can look it in the source code attached with the question, thanks so much if you can do it for me :D